# how to disable the click function while ajax running, same click starts ajax running, and after the ajax is complete, re-enable the click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, button, click

I have a click function starts a ajax post running, how do I disable the same click function while the ajax is running, and re-enable it after the ajax is completed? The code below shows what I want:

```
    $('input.btn_search').click(function () {
    var val_f_name = $('input.input_first').val();
    var val_l_name = $('input.input_last').val();
    var val_country = $('select.country').val();
    var val_state = $('.select.state').val();

    $('.popup_search_distor').css('height', '400px');
    $('img.ajax_loader').css('display','block');
    var xhr =  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $.vp + "signup/distLookup.ashx" + "?first=" + val_f_name + "&last=" + val_l_name + "&country=" + val_country + "&language=" + $.langID,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('img.ajax_loader').css('display','none');
            $('table.table_data').slideDown(600);
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function (k, v) {
                $('td.name').append(v.FirstName);

           });
        }
    });
```

Comment: onClick event of that button add attribute disabled = true and after ajax response remove disable attribute to the button markup

Comment: Just set the `disabled` property to `true` on click and set it to `false` when the Ajax callback is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input.btn_search').click(function () {
    var val_f_name = $('input.input_first').val();
    var val_l_name = $('input.input_last').val();
    var val_country = $('select.country').val();
    var val_state = $('.select.state').val();

    $('.popup_search_distor').css('height', '400px');
    $('img.ajax_loader').css('display','block');

    var that = $(this); //to reference the button easier
    that.attr('disabled',true); //disables the button

    var xhr =  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $.vp + "signup/distLookup.ashx" + "?first=" + val_f_name + "&last=" + val_l_name + "&country=" + val_country + "&language=" + $.langID,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('img.ajax_loader').css('display','none');
            $('table.table_data').slideDown(600);
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function (k, v) {
                $('td.name').append(v.FirstName);

           });

           that.attr('disabled',false); //enables the button the button

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to add a class or data-* attribute to the element. When you click on it, add that class/attribute and start the AJAX. Remove it when done. If clicked while AJAX is ongoing, that class/attribute is your indicator that it's still running, and you should not proceed until removed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code:

```
$('input.btn_search').click(function () {

    // Disable before ajax starts
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);

    var xhr =  $.ajax({

    success: function (data) {

       // Enable after ajax completes
       $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code :

```
 $('input.btn_search').click(function () {
    var val_f_name = $('input.input_first').val();
    var val_l_name = $('input.input_last').val();
    var val_country = $('select.country').val();
    var val_state = $('.select.state').val();

var thisbutton = $(this);
    thisbutton.attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $('.popup_search_distor').css('height', '400px');
    $('img.ajax_loader').css('display','block');
    var xhr =  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $.vp + "signup/distLookup.ashx" + "?first=" + val_f_name + "&last=" + val_l_name + "&country=" + val_country + "&language=" + $.langID,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('img.ajax_loader').css('display','none');
            $('table.table_data').slideDown(600);
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function (k, v) {
                $('td.name').append(v.FirstName);                    
           });
           thisbutton.removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
```

example : http://jsfiddle.net/oxrooqjf/2